# List a SQL SELECT result as column names and values pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have "Any" table (on a SQL Server 2016 Database) with any number of columns and rows. Let's call it `#temp`.

```
ID | NAME | PHONE
1  | John | 555-666-777
2  | Mary | 666-777-888
```

I want to get a `varchar(max)` variable filled by it's rows, but every column and value will be a row. Like this:

```
ID: 1
NAME: John
PHONE: 555-666-777

ID: 2
NAME: Mary
PHONE: 666-777-888
```

I don't want to specify the columns names on the query, I would like a solution that works for any table with any given number of columns and rows.

I also don't want to use a CURSOR as it's slow.

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: Look up dynamic pivot

Comment: *"SQL Server 2015 Database"* There never was a SQL Server 2015. There was 2014 and 2016, but there has never been a 2015 version.

Comment: Ok. Edited. Sorry.

Comment: [Edit] the question and include your current attempt and explain the problems with it.

Comment: I had not attempted at all. I was just hoping someone to drop a ready made code that I could use. But it's ok now... I ended up doing it myself. The code is on the answer of this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended doing it myself. Here's the code:

```
DECLARE @txtVar varchar(max)
-- Get all rows from the table in XML format. Each row will be delimited by a TR tag.
SET @txtVar = (SELECT * FROM #temp FOR XML PATH('TR'), ELEMENTS XSINIL)

-- Replace the Null values by "NULL" text literal
SET @txtVar = REPLACE(@txtVar, ' xsi:nil="true"/>', '>NULL' + char(13) )

-- Remove the row readers
SET @txtVar = REPLACE(@txtVar, '<TR xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">', '' )

-- Replace the row ending by a new line
SET @txtVar = REPLACE(@txtVar, '</TR>', CHAR(13) )

-- Replace the Fields names tags by the field name itself
SELECT @txtVar = REPLACE(REPLACE(@txtVar, '<' + name + '>', name + ': '), '</' + name + '>', CHAR(13) )
FROM tempdb.sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp')
```

The `#temp` table will be listed in plain text, and the text will be stored on the `@txtVar` variable.